# How to append sequential class names to <li> through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the most simple way of creating sequential class names inside a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat the iterarion plus 1 from your for loops in the class being add, for example:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < frets; i++){
  var fretRow = document.createElement("ul");
  fretRow.classList.add("fret-row-" + (i + 1));
  
  // 6 times, create a li item, add class "string, and append to the fretRow ^ 
  for(var j = 0; j < strings; j++){
    var fret = document.createElement("li");
    fret.classList.add("string-" + (j + 1));

    fretRow.appendChild(fret);
  }
 
  //append entire fretRow (now 'frets' and 'strings' to the fretboard div)
  fretboard.appendChild(fretRow);
}
```

Comment: `i` starts from zero, which should be 1 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use **"fret-row" + (i+1)** and **"string" + (j+1)**:

```
for(var i = 0; i < frets; i++){
  var fretRow = document.createElement("ul");
  fretRow.classList.add("fret-row" + (i+1));
  for(var j = 0; j < strings; j++){
    var fret = document.createElement("li");
    fret.classList.add("string" + (j+1));
    fretRow.appendChild(fret);
  }
  fretboard.appendChild(fretRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it changing your for loop like below. Change `fretRow.classList.add("fret-row")` to `fretRow.classList.add("fret-row", "fret-row"+(i+1));` and `fret.classList.add("string")` to `fret.classList.add("string"+(j+1))`

```
for(var i = 0; i < frets; i++){
   var fretRow = document.createElement("ul");
   fretRow.classList.add("fret-row", "fret-row"+(i+1));

   for(var j = 0; j < strings; j++){
        var fret = document.createElement("li");
        fret.classList.add("string"+(j+1));
        fretRow.appendChild(fret);
   }

   fretboard.appendChild(fretRow);
}
```

#### [CODE PEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKmzvd?editors=101)